# Add different sequential numbers in combobox in access bases another combobox

Tags: ms-access, combobox

I'm trying to add a list a sequential numbers in combobox 2 based on the choice made in combobox 1. I have a table that defines how many numbers need to be displayed in combobox2 based on the items in combobox1. What I need to do is that if the number is 3, then it should display 1,2,3 but if the number is 5, it should display 1,2,3,4,5 and so on.

Is this possible ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is possible.

The two easiest ways are probably:

1) Set the `RowSourceType` to **Value List**

Then build the string

```
1;2;3;...;n
```

in VBA and assign it to the `RowSource` Property.

---

2) Create and populate a Number Table (a single INT column, with values 1..n).

Set the `RowSourceType` to **Table/Query**

Set this `RowSource`:

```
SELECT NumCol FROM NumberTable 
WHERE NumCol <= [Combobox1].Value
```

so it will show the first x entries.